# What do you call the address of a company?

Tags: word-choice, business-japanese

Let's say you're asking someone if they need to know your company's address. What do you refer to that as? A 事務所? A 所在地?

Normally I only hear about 住所, but that sounds like it's only for regular people living somewhere.

For example, if you want to ask, like, "do you need to know my company's address?" (in order for the person you're talking to to mail something to them on my behalf, or perhaps to make out a receipt to them, or something), what word do people use to refer to such an address?

Are there different words you'd use in different situations? For example, at a store vs when talking to another company vs filling out some official form vs talking to a friend vs talking to someone at your own company?

I'm primarily wondering about the case where you're talking to a store or third party providing a service to you as an individual but who might need to know the address of your company (whether that's the headquarters or not is kind of out of scope of this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's commonly 住所, but I guess the technically correct term is 所在地. As you say, the former doesn't make much sense because in most companies nobody lives there, but it's still used, especially when spoken. It looks like people don't care about it too much. Even the health ministry uses 住所 in writing (while using 所在地, too): https://www.mhlw.go.jp/kouseiroudoushou/shozaiannai/index.html

You can use 番地 for the numeric part, too, in cases the rest (like the name of the city) doesn't need to be said. This might apply when talking about near-by stores.